# GameKit Framework not working on iPad

Tags: iphone, sdk

Hi have some problem with compiling GameKit framework on iPad , when xcode compiles my code , it takes me some error !!! i don't know what is it ?

[image]

Comment: Have you added the GameKit framework to your project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the GameKit Framework to your project. Right Click on the Framework Folder and select add Existing Framework. Either that, or you accidentally copied the GameKit Framework into your project directory. Just remove it from the directory, if that's the case.

Comment: thank you , i added from ExistingFrameworks but still have the same problem !!!! i don't know why !!

Comment: In ipadblueviewcontroller.h make sure you include #import and the game kit include. Smething like GameKit.h, Search SO for the correct line.

Comment: yes , i added #import<Gamekit/Gamekit.h> on project but still have this problem :( !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Do you have a folder  named GameKit.Framework in your project directory on disk?